# where logic error line files

Tags: c, string, file-io, line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXDIG   50
void main() {
   FILE     *f;
   int      j, i = 0;
   char   dig[MAXDIG];
   if ( !(f = fopen("H:\1\first", "r")) ) {
      printf("error opening file\n");
   }
   while (!feof(f)) {
      fscanf(f, "%c\n", &dig[i++]);
      if (i >= MAXDIG)
         break;
   }
   for (j=0; j < i; j++)
      printf("%c\n", dig[j]);
}
```

must show line, why it not (where error)? my workspace eclipse. sorry bad english. with new year

Comment: 2 Paul R i'm bad your realized "??? Ew..." ??? can more details say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to escape backslashes in your filename:

```
fopen("H:\\1\\first", "r")
```